# Filesystem keeps going read-only

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, boot-repair, read-only

As I said in the title, filesystem keeps going read-only every time I run `sudo apt autoremove` or `update-grub`.

I've tried formatting my Linux partition and installed Ubuntu again, did not work
tried to boot on an external drive and used boot-repair, still can't fix it.
Each time this happens I have to run `fsck` after restarting.

```
boot-repair-4ppa130                                              [20210420_1014]

============================= Boot Repair Summary ==============================



Default settings: ______________________________________________________________

The default repair of the Boot-Repair utility would reinstall the grub2 of
sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair would be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s      

User settings: _________________________________________________________________

The settings chosen by the user will reinstall the grub2 of
sda5 into the MBR of sda.
Additional repair will be performed: unhide-bootmenu-10s



========================= Reinstall the grub2 of sda5 ==========================

grub-install --version
grub-install (GRUB) 2.04-1ubuntu26.9

==> Reinstall the GRUB of sda5 into the MBR of sda

grub-install /dev/sda
Installing for i386-pc platform.
Installation finished. No error reported.

chroot /mnt/boot-sav/sda5 update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.elf
Found memtest86+ image: /boot/memtest86+.bin
/usr/lib/os-probes/mounted/20microsoft: 44: cannot create /tmp/os-prober.BdYkgJ/os-prober.tmp: Read-only file system
mv: cannot stat '/tmp/os-prober.BdYkgJ/os-prober.tmp': No such file or directory
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Read-only file system
rmdir: failed to remove '/var/lib/os-prober/mount': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/os-prober.BdYkgJ/dmraid-map': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/os-prober.BdYkgJ/swaps-map': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/os-prober.BdYkgJ/raided-map': Read-only file system
rm: cannot remove '/tmp/os-prober.BdYkgJ/mounted-map': Read-only file system
Found Windows 10 on /dev/sda1
cat: write error: Read-only file system

Unhide GRUB boot menu in sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg
mv: inter-device move failed: '/var/log/boot-repair/20210420_101436/sda5/grub.cfg_new' to '/mnt/boot-sav/sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg'; unable to remove target: Read-only file system

An error occurred during the repair.

You can now reboot your computer.


============================ Boot Info After Repair ============================

 => Grub2 (v2.00) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub. It also embeds following components:
    
    modules
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    fshelp ext2 part_msdos biosdisk
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 => Syslinux MBR (5.00 and higher) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  Windows 10
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows 8/2012: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab /etc/default/grub 
                       /boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  SYSLINUX 6.04
    Boot sector info:  Syslinux looks at sector 32792 of /dev/sdb1 for its 
                       second stage. The integrity check of Syslinux failed. 
                       No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /syslinux.cfg 
                       /efi/BOOT/grubx64.efi /efi/BOOT/mmx64.efi /ldlinux.sys


================================ 3 OS detected =================================

OS#1:   Windows 10 (boot) on sda1
OS#2:   Windows 10 on sda2
OS#3:   Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS on sda5

============================ Architecture/Host Info ============================

CPU architecture: 64-bit
Live-session OS is Ubuntu 64-bit (Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, focal, x86_64)


===================================== UEFI =====================================

This live-session is not in EFI-mode.
EFI in dmesg.
[    0.012309] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000008CFFC000 000236 (v01 HPQOEM INSYDE   00000001 HP   00040000)
[    0.012312] ACPI: UEFI 0x000000008CFFB000 000042 (v01 HPQOEM INSYDE   00000002 HP   00040000)
This session has been detected as 'live' because df -Th / contains overlay



============================= Drive/Partition Info =============================

Disks info: ____________________________________________________________________

sda : notGPT,   no-BIOSboot,    has-noESP,  not-usb,    not-mmc, has-os,    2048 sectors * 512 bytes

Partitions info (1/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   not-far
sda2    : is-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda3    : no-os,    32, nopakmgr,   no-docgrub, nogrub, nogrubinstall,  no-grubenv, noupdategrub,   farbios
sda5    : is-os,    64, apt-get,    grub-pc ,   grub2,  grub-install,   grubenv-ok, update-grub,    farbios

Partitions info (2/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda2    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  haswinload, no-recov-nor-hid,   bootmgr,    is-winboot
sda3    : isnotESP, part-has-no-fstab,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot
sda5    : isnotESP, fstab-without-efi,  no-nt,  no-winload, no-recov-nor-hid,   no-bmgr,    notwinboot

Partitions info (3/3): _________________________________________________________

sda1    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda2    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda3    : not-sepboot,  no-boot,    part-has-no-fstab,  not-sep-usr,    no---usr,   part-has-no-fstab,  std-grub.d, sda
sda5    : not-sepboot,  with-boot,  fstab-without-boot, not-sep-usr,    with--usr,  fstab-without-usr,  std-grub.d, sda

fdisk -l (filtered): ___________________________________________________________

Disk sda: 931.53 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk identifier: 0xc2b88944
      Boot     Start        End    Sectors  Size Id Type
sda1            2048     104447     102400   50M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda2  *       104448  306176727  306072280  146G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
sda3       306178048  307199999    1021952  499M 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE
sda4       307202046 1953523711 1646321666  785G  5 Extended
sda5       307202048 1953523711 1646321664  785G 83 Linux
Disk sdb: 7.38 GiB, 7914651648 bytes, 15458304 sectors
Disk identifier: 0x0016bfe9
      Boot Start      End  Sectors  Size Id Type
sdb1  *     2048 15458303 15456256  7.4G  c W95 FAT32 (LBA)

parted -lm (filtered): _________________________________________________________

sda:1000GB:scsi:512:4096:msdos:ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD1:;
1:1049kB:53.5MB:52.4MB:ntfs::;
2:53.5MB:157GB:157GB:ntfs::boot;
3:157GB:157GB:523MB:ntfs::msftres;
4:157GB:1000GB:843GB:::;
5:157GB:1000GB:843GB:ext4::;
sdb:7915MB:scsi:512:512:msdos:Kingston DataTraveler 2.0:;
1:1049kB:7915MB:7914MB:fat32::boot, lba;

blkid (filtered): ______________________________________________________________

NAME   FSTYPE   UUID                                 PARTUUID                             LABEL           PARTLABEL
sda                                                                                                       
├─sda1 ntfs     E49445D99445AF3C                     c2b88944-01                          System Reserved 
├─sda2 ntfs     58B84B39B84B14C2                     c2b88944-02                                          
├─sda3 ntfs     384872D74872937C                     c2b88944-03                                          
├─sda4                                               c2b88944-04                                          
└─sda5 ext4     c6fab2b2-162e-40e2-b8d3-2f4ad696c741 c2b88944-05                                          
sdb                                                                                                       
└─sdb1 vfat     9C27-ED04                            0016bfe9-01                          UBUNTU 20_0     

df (filtered): _________________________________________________________________

                   Avail Use% Mounted on
sda1               23.7M  53% /mnt/boot-sav/sda1
sda2                 21G  86% /mnt/boot-sav/sda2
sda3               86.1M  83% /mnt/boot-sav/sda3
sda5                723G   1% /mnt/boot-sav/sda5
sdb1                4.7G  36% /cdrom

Mount options: __________________________________________________________________

sda1              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda2              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda3              rw,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,allow_other,blksize=4096
sda5              ro,relatime
sdb1              ro,noatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro

====================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu   c6fab2b2-162e-40e2-b8d3-2f4ad696c741
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-50-generic   c6fab2b2-162e-40e2-b8d3-2f4ad696c741
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-43-generic   c6fab2b2-162e-40e2-b8d3-2f4ad696c741
Windows 10 (on sda1)   E49445D99445AF3C
Windows 10 (on sda2)   58B84B39B84B14C2
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

========================== sda5/etc/fstab (filtered) ===========================

# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=c6fab2b2-162e-40e2-b8d3-2f4ad696c741 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0

======================= sda5/etc/default/grub (filtered) =======================

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

==================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
 612.619647980 = 657.795338240  boot/grub/grub.cfg                             2
 332.742027283 = 357.279031296  boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img                     1
 589.267902374 = 632.721592320  boot/vmlinuz                                   1
 151.540035248 = 162.714873856  boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-43-generic                  2
 589.267902374 = 632.721592320  boot/vmlinuz-5.8.0-50-generic                  1
 151.540035248 = 162.714873856  boot/vmlinuz.old                               2
 155.692825317 = 167.173898240  boot/initrd.img                                1
 155.744766235 = 167.229669376  boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-43-generic               2
 155.692825317 = 167.173898240  boot/initrd.img-5.8.0-50-generic               1
 155.744766235 = 167.229669376  boot/initrd.img.old                            2

===================== sda5: ls -l /etc/grub.d/ (filtered) ======================

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 17622 Jan 13 14:12 10_linux
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 42359 Jan 13 14:12 10_linux_zfs
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12894 Jan 13 14:12 20_linux_xen
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 12059 Jan 13 14:12 30_os-prober
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  1424 Jan 13 14:12 30_uefi-firmware
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   214 Jan 13 14:12 40_custom
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root   216 Jan 13 14:12 41_custom

====================== sdb1/boot/grub/grub.cfg (filtered) ======================

Ubuntu
Ubuntu (safe graphics)
OEM install (for manufacturers)
Boot from next volume
UEFI Firmware Settings

========================= sdb1/syslinux.cfg (filtered) =========================

DEFAULT loadconfig

LABEL loadconfig
  CONFIG /isolinux/isolinux.cfg
  APPEND /isolinux/

==================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Grub ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             boot/grub/grub.cfg                             1

================== sdb1: Location of files loaded by Syslinux ==================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)
            ?? = ??             syslinux.cfg                                   1
            ?? = ??             ldlinux.sys                                    1


=============================== StdErr Messages ================================

File descriptor 63 (pipe:[69810]) leaked on lvs invocation. Parent PID 7355: /bin/bash
```

Comment: 1. Boot Repair is not for such situation. Whatever happens after Grub is not a boot issue and Boot Repair has nothing to do with it. 2. Becoming read-only or corrupted file systems for no known reason frequently are symptoms of an about to fail drive.

Comment: Have you checked your hardware's health?  When a *file-system* flips from RW to RO there is a cause, if it occurs repeatedly chances are there is reason that needs investigation & fix so don't ignore the warning signs of hardware issues.  I'd start with drive health (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) but note it's not the only cause...

Comment: thank you guys for replying, @guiverc i will check it out